# Managing deployments for nodes running Camel routes

Tags: deployment, jboss, apache-camel, apache-karaf

I have an enterprise application that uses Camel routes and need to be able to provision/start/stop nodes running these Camel routes on multiple machines.

I am looking at Apache Karaf and JBoss Switchyard as 2 solutions to help me deploy and manage these routes. I think I understand the value of Apache Karaf since it is a osgi container and I can un/deploy new routes into it. Will JBoss Switchyard also help me for this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**JBoss Fuse**

JBoss Fuse which includes Fuse Fabric can manage and provision containers in a cluster / cloud / etc.

- http://fuse.fusesource.org/fabric/

JBoss Fuse uses Karaf as the container. So what you can do with Karaf you can do as well with JBoss Fuse.

On top of that Fuse Fabric brings to the table, all the cluster provisioning and management. And with a distributed registry for HA et all.

With JBoss Fuse you can deploy and manage your Camel routes in a cluster. And perform rolling upgrades / downgrades across the nodes in the cluster, and much more. And to go along with that you have commands in the Karaf Shell to perform actions, and as well a web console UI based on http://hawt.io/.

*Short answer:* Yes JBoss Fuse can manage and provision your Camel routes in a cluster.

**SwitchYard**

In terms of JBoss SwitchYard, then it uses JBoss Application Server / WildFly as its container (at this time of writing SY does not yet support OSGi). So SY leverages the clustering and management support from JBoss Application Server.

Comment: Thank you for the comparison, looks like Fuse/Karaf is the most useful  at this time.

Answer (score 1):

Yes with Apache Karaf you'll be able to deploy/undeploy routes by either installing the appropriate bundle or by installing the corresponding blueprint.xml (containing the route) as Karaf supports deploying of various xml files (which are generated to bundles at runtime). This will give you an easy way of deploying / Developing. Also available with karaf is the def:watch command, it'll help you with developing Bundles cause it will watch your file/maven-repo location for updates and will install those immediately in the container. 
For distributing your routes throughout a cluster there is also Apache Karaf - Cellar, a subproject for maintaining Cluster ability for the Karaf container.

Answer (score 0):

take a look at [Zookeeper](http://camel.apache.org/zookeeper.html) and its support for distributed route policies...

also, check out these master election examples

- http://www.systemmobile.com/?p=399
- http://frommyworkshop.blogspot.com/2013/06/leader-election-of-camel-router-through.html